# Add ODR resources programmatically

Tags: xcode, scripting, on-demand-resources

I am having list of files added as ODR resources to my Xcode project. When I create new files, I have to add them again as ODR Resources with ODR Resource Tags. I am getting the new files very frequently which I am adding it again and again. Is there any way to automate adding the ODR resources ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific library or tool to add the ODR resources to the Xcode project programmatically. The JS library [Xcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xcode) used by Cordova can be used to edit and add Resources (need to specify ODR tags) to the pbxproj file.